Is there any advantage to using high slot width in deep space optical communication with pulse position modulation?
Optical communication across large distances is superior to radio communication due to lower divergence. My question is about the optimization of pulse position modulation (PPM) parameters to achieve the highest distance.
For an additive white Gaussian noise channel, the probability of detection is determined by (Ep/tp)/N0, where Ep is the energy in the pulse, tp is the pulse duration or slot width, N0 is the noise power spectral density. If pulse peak power (Ep/tp = Pp) is constant the detection probability is independent of pulse duration. Considering that a lower slot width results in a higher bit rate, it seems that low pulse widths are preferable if the peak power is constant.
On the other hand, the most effective way of detecting extremely low-intensity light from space is superconducting nanowire single-photon detectors (SNSPDs). SNSPDs have a rather large dead time after photon detection, approximately 10-30 ns. Thus, it might be advantageous to have a slot width larger than the dead time to allow multiple firings by a single SNSPD for the same pulse, which can increase detection sensitivity and the communication distance.
My questions are the following: Does the last paragraph about SNSPDs make sense? Are there other noise sources whose impact decreases with increasing detection time (i.e., slot width), making longer slot widths more advantageous for extremely high distances (provided peak power is the same)?

This is an interesting question! Superconducting nanowire detection is mentioned in several places here and many posts link to external resources, but I don't think there's been such a rigorous treatment yet. There are almost 200 Stack Exchange sites and one of them that might be helpful if you don't get an answer here is Signal Processing SE. If you search "nanowire" you'll see an answer I posted there, but again it doesn't cover your question yet.

It's strongly discouraged to post the same question simultaneously on multiple SE sites. Have a look around there, and if you don't get an answer here in a week or so you can consider clicking "flag" and select moderator assistance and you can ask for help migrating this question there. Welcome to Stack Exchange!
